# Arraylist member of viewstate's triplet requires explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I've been reading article about [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), and I stumbled across this:

> The Page class contains a SavePageViewState(), which is invoked during the page life cycle's save    view state stage. The SavePageViewState() method starts by creating a Triplet that contains the following three items: 
>   1. The page's hash code. This hash code is used to ensure that the view state hasn't been tampered  with between postbacks. We'll talk more about view state hashing in the "View State and Security Implications" section.
>   2. The collective view state of the Page's control hierarchy.
>   3. An ArrayList of controls in the control hierarchy that need to be explicitly invoked by the page  class during the raise postback event stage of the life cycle.

And I kinda don't understand the third point, about arraylist.
If anyone could help me out, either by explaining, or supplying with an example - I'd be grateful.

Comment: [Understanding ASP.NET VIEWState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: I surely did Chris.. thanks